# New Column by lambda if-else but getting NaNs

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe loking like this:

```
     col1    label 
 0  value1  label1  
 1  value2  label2   
 2  value2  label1 label2
```

For each label, I want to create a new  column, indicating if this label occures in this row:

```
     col1    label        label1  label2
 0  value1  label1          1       0
 1  value2  label2          0       1
 2  value2  label1 label2   1       1
```

What I tried:

```
#iterating through all occuring labels (strings)
for label in labels:
    grouped[label] = df.apply(lambda row: 1 if label in row['label'] else 0, axis=1))
```

But this results in NaNs:

```
      col1    label        label1  label2
 0  value1  label1          NaN      NaN
 1  value2  label2          NaN      NaN
 2  value2  label1 label2   NaN      NaN
```

Where is my error? And/or is there a better way to solve this?

**Edit:**
found my error, in the loop are two different Dataframes which should only be one:

```
for label in labels:
    grouped[label] = df.apply(lambda row: 1 if label in row['label'] else 0, axis=1))
```

Comment: We are missing information here. What is "subcategory" and "labels" here. Furthermore on row number 2, are these strings separated by a whitespace?

Comment: Use `df = df.join(df['label'].str.get_dummies(' '))`

Comment: @jezrael perfect, this should be an answer. But still, why is my solution not working exactly?

Comment: maybe change `grouped[label]` to `df[label]` in loop

Comment: tested, for me working well, only remove last `)`

Comment: I am happy to accept an answer, else I will vote to delete this question as this was evidently just an error caused by inattention :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where is my error? And/or is there a better way to solve this?

There is error for assign wrong `DataFrame` called `grouped` like I mention in comments, also last `)` is removed:

```
for label in labels:
    df[label] = df.apply(lambda row: 1 if label in row['label'] else 0, axis=1)
```

Non loop solution should be test by [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and convert `True/False` to `1/0` by [`Series.view`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html):

```
labels = ['label1','label2']
#iterating through all occuring labels (strings)
for label in labels:
    df[label] = df['label'].str.contains(label).view('i1')
print (df)
     col1          label  label1  label2
0  value1         label1       1       0
1  value2         label2       0       1
2  value2  label1 label2       1       1
```

If values are separated by spaces is possible use [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
df = df.join(df['label'].str.get_dummies(' '))
```